# How to add a hyphen between the two dates in html and space-between evenly

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[image: Can't add hyphen]

Between the trip dates I'd like to add a hyphen then spread them the entire width evenly but I can't get it to work.  And I'd like to left justify 'Enter destination'.  How would I do that and add a hyphen between the start and finish date so that it's expanded the entire width of the page?

```
    <ion-label>Destination</ion-label>
<ion-item>
    <input [(ngModel)]="destination" placeholder="Enter destination" 
#destin>
</ion-item>
<ion-label>Trip dates</ion-label>
<ion-item flex>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="startDate"> . 
 </ion-datetime>
    <p class="hyphen">--</p>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="endDate"></ion- 
  datetime>
</ion-item>
```

CSS

```
        .hyphen{
        display: flex;
        width: 100px;
        height: 24px;
        font-family: Gotham;
        font-size: 24px;
        align-items: flex-start;
        align-content: center;
        flex: auto;
    }

    .flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to believe you can do something like this:

```
<div>
    <p style="display: inline-block; float: left;">12/23/2019</p>
    <p class="hyphen" style="display: inline-block;">--</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block; float: right;">12/23/2020</p>
  </div>
```

Note: it's just a sample, take note of the styling precisely, Thank you.

Comment: That didn't work...however, it looks a lot better after I abandoned the IONIC datetime and used regular date element.